# ¿Se puede combinar archivos comunes php con estructura POO de php?

Tags: php, poo, php5

**Mi código es el siguiente:**

***conexionbd.php***

```
<?php
$credenciales_bd;
/**Comprueba si el archivo db.php.ini existe*/
if (file_exists("../config/config.php.ini")) {
try{
    /*Lee el archivo db.php.ini*/
    $credenciales_bd= parse_ini_file('../config/config.php.ini');
    /*Obtiene valores del archivo db.php.ini*/
    $host= $credenciales_bd['servidor'];
    $usuario=$credenciales_bd['user'];
    $contrasena=$credenciales_bd['pass'];
    $bd=$credenciales_bd['bd'];
    /*Crea la conexion MySQL*/
    $conn= new mysqli($host,$usuario,$contrasena,$bd);

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo '<script>$e</script>';
}
}else{

}
```

mi duda es, **¿Puedo combinar el archivo anterior en una estructura de `POO` de `php`?** Esto debido a que quiero reutilizar ese código, y utilizar `POO` ya que tengo que hacer varias consultas `MySQL` y quisiera tenerlas en funciones dentro de un mismo documento.

Lo que quiero hacer es algo como lo siguiente:

```
<?PHP
 class Consultas_usuario{

 include("conexionbd.php");

 $conexion=$conn;

  public function consulta1(){

   $conexion->query(...);

   /*Resto del codigo*/

 }
 }
```

Comment: Claro que puedes. Pero tendrás que escribir clases, como muestras en la segunda parte del código, sabiendo que algunas cosas van a variar. Por ejemplo, las variables de la clase serían miembros de ella: private, public, protected... y para usar tu conexión tendrás que crear una nueva instancia de tu clase (recomiendo que le des un nombre más descriptivo y que apliques una convención de nombres adecuada). Yo haría una clase `Conexion` que me conecte a la base de datos y la dotaría de varios métodos, entre ellos una para consultas. Para usarla: `$db=new Conexion();`

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que entiendo es que dentro de la misma clase creo un método que me devuelva el valor de la conexión y ese método lo puedo instanciar en los otros para hacer mis consultas, ¿Es así?

Comment: @A.Cedano mi idea era tener un código aparte para la conexión (un archivo independiente) y ese archivo heredarlo solamente para todos los archivos que lo fueran a utilizar.

Comment: Puede ser así o puedes tener una clase más completa que te gestione no solamente la conexión, sino también las consultas y las respuestas a dichas consultas. Eso depende de ti y del alcance de tu aplicación.

Comment: @A.Cedano por ejemplo: tengo que hacer consultas como administrador y como capturista, si hiciera una clase para cada uno, ¿tendría que crear un método conexión en cada clase?

Comment: Por ejemplo [esta es la clase que yo uso para manejar mis conexiones](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO). Es una clase de largo alcance, para manejar con facilidad todo lo relativo a la base de datos, sin complicaciones. La misma se puede ampliar, mejorar, refinar, personalizar...

Comment: Puede ser la misma clase, con diferentes métodos de conexión. En la misma clase puedes tener por ejemplo `connectAdmin` y allí conectas como administrador, verificando antes que el usuario que usa el script sea realmente administrador... luego otro método `connectCapturista`, donde conectas con las credenciales del capturista.  Quizá tengas que leer las contraseñas desde un archivo de credenciales al que sólo tenga acceso el administrador, ya que si un capturista puede editar el archivo de conexiones y tienes allí las claves, podrá conocer la clave de administrador.

Comment: @A.Cedano excelente voy a implementar, cualquier duda preguntare, buen aporte.